# How can I update the text of a JButton when I click on it?

Tags: java, swing, refresh, jbutton, jlabel

I assume there is a better way than removing every element from the JPanel and remaking them, because that's the workaround I had but now obviously when the button is clicked it's told to remove itself so the action never completes.

Here's my awful code for adding the button action listener:

```
// Add action listener to increment quest progress when button is pushed
        listOfButtons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                questList[temp].incrementNumerator(1);
                refreshButtons();
            }
        });
```

Here's my awful code for "refreshing" the JButtons:

```
// Use when updating data that a JButton displays, destroys & recreates all     JButtons on the window
private void refreshButtons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfButtons.length; i++) {

        // Remove each JButtons from the JFrame
        contentPane.remove(listOfButtons[i]);
    }
    addButtons();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get hold of the `JButton` reference from the `ActionEvent` itself.

```
listOfButtons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        questList[temp].incrementNumerator(1);
        ((JButton) e.getSource()).setText(questList[temp].getValue());
    }
});
```

I've used `questList[temp].getValue()` just as an example. You'll obviously pass what works for your program.